# C++ Is there a way to replace multiple tokens in a string

Tags: c++

I am working on a simple terminal shell and I was wondering if there was a way to replace multiple variable tokens in a string with other values.

Given something like `PATH = $PATH:$CWD`, this would be transformed into `PATH = /usr/bin:/usr`

My current code can only handle one variable in a string. The variable can only be replaced if the token is followed by a non-alphanumeric character.

```
string varInterp(string &token)
{
    int startIndex = -1, endIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < token.size(); i++)
    {
        if (token[i] == '$')
        {
            startIndex = i;
            int j = i+1;
            while (isalnum(token[j]) && j < token.size())
            {
                endIndex = j;
                j++;
            }
            if (j == token.size())
                endIndex = -1;
        }
    }
    if (startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1)
    {
        int varLen = endIndex - startIndex;
        string varName = token.substr(startIndex+1,varLen);
        string varVal = globalVars.getVal(varName);
        token.replace(startIndex,varLen+1,varVal);
    }
    return token;
}
```

Comment: Add more `if` statements to handle additional token replacements. eg: `else if (token[i] == ':') { do the work }`

Comment: *I was wondering if there was a way to replace multiple variable tokens in a string with other values.* -- Of course there is a way.  If not, C++ would be one of the weakest computer programming language to have existed.

Comment: Is the string always separated by `:`?

Answer (score 0):

The one possible solution is how to parse big string is to use stack like in simple calculator. You just pushing in stack step by step all string split it for small meaningfull blocks.
This code is very not perfect, i just show the following idea here.

```
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


std::string parser(std::string str)
{
    std::map <std::string, std::string> symbols = { {"PATH", "/usr/bin"},{"CWD", "/usr"} };
    std::stack<std::string> stack_;
    std::string currentToken;
    bool inToken = false;
    for (auto i =0;i<str.size();i++)
    {
        if (inToken)
        {
            auto it = symbols.find(currentToken);

            if (it==symbols.end()) currentToken += str[i];
            else 
            {
                inToken = false;
                stack_.push(symbols[currentToken]);
                currentToken.clear();
                i--;
            }

            //this code duplicates block just if it last char in string is last symbol of token
            it = symbols.find(currentToken);
            if (it != symbols.end() && (i == str.size() - 1))
            {
                inToken = false;
                stack_.push(symbols[currentToken]);
                currentToken.clear();
            }
        }
        else if (str[i] == '$')
        {
            currentToken += str[++i];
            inToken = true;
        }
        else
            stack_.push(std::string()+str[i]);
    }

    std::string result;
    while (stack_.size())
    {
        result.insert(0,stack_.top());
        stack_.pop();
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << parser("$PATH:$CWD");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function to replace str1 by str2 inside an str, use a combination of [string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and [string::replace](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)

firstly, you find the position of str1 in str

```
size_t pos = str.find(str1);
```

then, you can use replace to replace characters from `pos` to `pos + str1.length()` in str with str2

```
str.replace(pos, str1.length(), str2);
```

now, when you have that function, you can use it with some `if` conditions to replace any token you want inside a string